# Water leakage in basement after down spout installation

Tags: basement, gutters, contractors, leaking, downspout

Large amounts of water have been leaking into my basement after below ground downspouts were installed in November of 2022. Prior to the installation, there was never any water leakage in the basement. The contractor who installed looked at the down spouts and thought not enough dirt was added to the area where the gutter drain feeds into the downspouts and added additional dirt, but the problem persists. Earlier this week there was a severe rainstorm and the entire basement carpet was heavily saturated with water.

I went outside during the storm and looked at the downspouts. There was water inside nearly to the top at both the entry part from the gutters and the drainage end of the downspouts, but it did not look like the water was moving out of the drainage end, or overflowing at the entry point where water from the gutters drains into the downspout.

I am a recent first time homebuyer, not very handy, and limited in what I can do myself because of health and disabilities. If water continues to leak into my basement I will have to replace the carpeting which is an expense I cannot afford at this time.  Any help in solving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: pictures added

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is possible the below-ground downspouts have a significant leak but that's rare in my experience; much more often there's some kind of blockage. Can you tell if there's blockage in the underground portions? Can you post some pictures?

Comment: This is really disappointing. Could you get the contractor back to look at the situation?

Comment: @isherwood thank you for your feedback! I have added picture of the downspout. The downspout pictured is in the same area where water is leaking into the basement from the floor. The window in the first picture is the basement area.

Comment: @FredricShope thank you for your feedback! I went outside during the rainstorm this week and looked inside of the downspout by using a flashlight. There was water inside visible at both ends nearly to the top, but it did not appear to reach the exit through the green cap or overflow at the point where water enters the downspout. I’ve included pictures of the installation.

Comment: @JimStewart the contractor looked at it a couple of weeks ago and thought it was an issue with more of the dirt needing to be added around entry point of the downspout. I’ve asked him to come back out and examine it again prior to our next rainstorm this upcoming Tuesday, but he has not committed to a date or time yet.

Comment: Your grade is already higher than it should be--siding should be well above the soil. You may need to carve swales into the yard out 10-15 feet to encourage better drainage away from the home.

Comment: @isherwood Thank you again for your feedback! Any idea why this is suddenly a problem? Prior to the instillation the finished basement area never had water leakage of any kind. I didn’t see excess water/pools of water near the downspouts during or after the rainstorm. Prior to this there were pipes from the gutter at about the same distance as the exit point for the downspouts.

Comment: You said yourself that the pipe is blocked. these things are not generally completely watertight. That's the fairly obvious first step. If I had anything further for you I'd post an answer.

Comment: Use a hose as a probe to see if the drains are open. Push a hose (without the water on) into the drain and see if you can get it to the outlet of the drain.

Comment: Are the below-grade sections of piping perforated at all?  If not, you are either getting a lot of bypass at the rectangular-to-round fitting (meaning your underground pipe has insufficient capacity), or your emitter isn't working properly.  IDK if sealing the transition joint is "done" but I would certainly consider trying to seal any above-ground joints in an effort to force the water to the emitter.